# How to resize form while keeping it at the centre of the screen?

Tags: vb.net, window-resize

I have a vb.net form.
I used the following tutorial to add shadow and moving/resizing feature to my form.

[Metro-UI-Zune-like-Interface-form](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138661/Metro-UI-Zune-like-Interface-form)

It is working fine but my problem is that i want that whenever my form is resized,
it should remain at the centre of the screen (or, if i resize it from bottom, it resizes from the top & bottom both half-half).

I have used this :

```
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Height) / 2
    Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width) / 2
End Sub
```

But whenever i resize it, after the resizing, the form moves to the position of the mouse pointer.
The mouse pointer is outside the form window since it resizes half half in both opposite directions.

It causes flickering and it changes the position of the form.

Any ideas how i can implement this smoothly ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Declare 2 variables to keep the desktop screen resolutions

> Dim dx, dy As Integer

on form load get the screen resolutions and them in dx & dy

> ```
>   dx = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width
>   dy = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height
> ```

and finally, on a resize event do the following

> Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeEnd

```
      Dim x, y As Integer

      x = Me.Width / 2

      y = Me.Height / 2

      Me.Location = New Point(dx / 2 - x, dy / 2 - y)
```

> End Sub

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `Form.CenterToScreen()` method:

```
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Me.CenterToScreen()
End Sub
```

Read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

---

Yes, I know the article says that it's not intended to be used from your code, but I've seen other professional programmers use it without a problem. :)